# Identify symbols in string

Tags: python, tokenize

I am implementing a simple DSL. I have the following input string:

```
txt = 'Hi, my name is <<name>>. I was born in <<city>>.'
```

And I have the following data:

```
{ 
  'name': 'John',
  'city': 'Paris',
  'more': 'xxx',
  'data': 'yyy',
  ...
}
```

I need to implement the following function:

```
def tokenize(txt):
    ...
    return fmt, vars
```

Where I get:

```
fmt = 'Hi, my name is {name}. I was born in {city}.'
vars = ['name', 'city']
```

That is, `fmt` can be passed to the [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function, and `vars` is a list of the detected tokens (so that I can perform lookup in the data, which can be more complex than what I described, since it can be split in several namespaces)

After this, processing the format would be simple:

```
def expand(fmt, vars, data):
    params = get_params(vars, data)
    return fmt.format(params)
```

Where `get_params` is performing simple lookup of the data, and returning something like:

```
params = {
  'name': 'John',
  'city': 'Paris',
}
```

My question is:

How can I implement tokenize? How can I detect the tokens, knowing that the delitimers are `<<` and `>>`? Should I go for regexes, or is there an easier path?

This is something similar to what `pystache`, or even `.format` itself, are doing, but I would like a light-weight implementation. Robustness is not very critical at this stage.

Comment: You could probably use regexes. Look for something like `/\<\<([A-Za-z0-9]+)\>\>/g`. Check this out: https://regex101.com/r/rT8sH9/1

Comment: @MichaelZhang: thanks, great regex helper!

Comment: @MichaelZhang -- you posted first; do you want to write up a more complete response as an answer, so delavnog can accept that one?

Comment: A regex seems the simplest solution, if you had a single character delimiter it would be simple using string.Template but with what you have  I don't see an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a perfect target for regexp.  Find the begin/end quotation marks, replace them with braces, and extract the symbol names into a list.  Do you have a solid description of legal symbols?  You'll want a search such as

```
/\<\<([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\>\>/
```

For classical variable names (note that this excludes leading underscores).  Are you familiar enough with regexps to take it from here?

Comment: Sure, thanks, good starting point. I wanted to make sure that I am not going into a rabbit hole with this - I thought maybe there is a better option to identify tokens which I was not seeing at the moment.

Comment: You don't need to escape,  `re.sub("<<(.*?)>>", "{"r"\1""}", s)` would also replace the `<<>>` with `{}`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def tokenize(text):
    found_variables = []
    def replace_and_capture(match):
        found_variables.append(match.group(1))
        return "{{{}}}".format(match.group(1))
    return re.sub(r'<<([^>]+)>>', replace_and_capture, text), found_variables

fmt, vars = tokenize('Hi, my name is <<name>>. I was born in <<city>>.')
print(fmt)
print(vars)

# Output:
# Hi, my name is {name}. I was born in {city}.
# ['name', 'city']
```

Comment: might help the OP and future readers if you added a little explanation

Comment: It works as advertised, but the choice of a filter function is a bit odd, instead of looping through the regex groups

Comment: @delavnog Why do you say that? If you loop over the found groups, you need to do the substitution "by hand." This seemed simpler.